Flutter have abnormal audio channels when playing videos on the iOS
I'm not very familiar with Flutter development, but there's an issue with an open-source application I'm using. I'd like to ask friends with iOS cross-platform development experience, is there a difference between AudioSessionConfiguration.music() and AudioSessionConfiguration.playback()?
The player I am currently using is set to AudioSessionConfiguration.music(). There is an issue on the iOS side where some videos have no sound if the mute mode is turned on during video playback. The media player status bar in the control center does not show anything either. However, once the mute mode is turned off, the sound appears. It seems very much like the media sound is being routed through the notification sound audio channel. I look forward to your response.
 Future<void> initSession() async {
    session = await AudioSession.instance;
    session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.music());

I tried to manage the lifecycle of the audio component to prevent it from interrupting several times during video playback, but this is not the root cause of the issue.
I tried to troubleshoot whether the configuration was overwritten during the initialization of other components, but the issue does not exist.

It looks like Flutter's AudioSessionConfiguration doesn't map exactly on to iOS's AVAudioSession categories, however if you need to ignore the mute switch and integrate with the media controls, you'd use the playback category, which probably correspond's to Flutter's AudioSessionConfiguration.playback(), so why not use that?
